# Help understanding PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

First of all, we are given a function $u(x,y):\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Which satisfies the Minimal Surface Equation:
$$
(1+u_x^2)u_{yy} - 2u_xu_yu_{xy} + (1+u_y^2)u_{xx} = 0
$$

---

Now we are told that the functions $\phi_1 = \arctan\big( u_x \big)$ and $\phi_2 = \arctan\big( u_y \big)$ are solutions of the equation:
$$
(1+u_x^2)v_{yy} - 2u_xu_yv_{xy} + (1+u_y^2)v_{xx} = 0
$$
I do not understand what it actually means to say that these functions are solutions of the equation. My intuition is that we must replace $v$ with each one of the $\phi_i$'s and verify that the equation is satisfied. But I could also be mistaken as it is not clear that the $u$ in the first part is the same as the $u$ in the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need to replace  $v$ with $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ and then need to use the fact that $u$ also satisfies minimal surface equation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I cannot seem to be able to prove that either $\phi_i$ satisfies this! Have you been able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For $\phi_1= \arctan(u_x)$ we have
\begin{align*}
{\phi_1}_{yy}=& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\arctan(u_x)= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (u_{xy} \frac{1}{1+u_x^2}) \\
=& u_{xyy}\frac{1}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xy}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \frac{1}{1+u_x^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xyy}}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xy}  \frac{-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(1+u_x^2)}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xyy}}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xy}  \frac{-2u_{xy}u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2}
\end{align*}
,
\begin{align*}
{\phi_1}_{xx}=& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\arctan(u_x)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u_{xx} \frac{1}{1+u_x^2}) \\
=& u_{xxx}\frac{1}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xx}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \frac{1}{1+u_x^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xxx}}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xx}  \frac{-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(1+u_x^2)}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xxx}}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xx}  \frac{-2u_{xx}u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
{\phi_1}_{xy}=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u_{xy}\frac{1}{1+u_x^2}) \\
=& u_{xxy}\frac{1}{1+u_x^2}+ u_{xy}\frac{-2u_{xx}u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xxy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}u_{xy}u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2}
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
(1+u_x^2){\phi_1}_{yy}- 2u_xu_y{\phi_1}_{xy}=& (1+u_x^2)\frac{u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2}- 2u_xu_y\frac{u_{xxy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}u_{xy}u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2} 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
(1+u_y^2){\phi_1}_{xx}=& \frac{(u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_x)(1+u_y^2)}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_x +u_y^2u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_xu_y^2}{(1+u_x^2)^2}
\end{align*}

Adding both:
\begin{align*}
(1+u_x^2){\phi_1}_{yy}- 2u_xu_y{\phi_1}_{xy}&+ (1+u_y^2){\phi_1}_{xx}= \frac{(1+u_x^2)(u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x)}{(1+u_x^2)^2}- 2u_xu_y\frac{u_{xxy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}u_{xy}u_x}{(1+u_x^2)^2} + \frac{u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_x +u_y^2u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_xu_y^2}{(1+u_x^2)^2} \\
=& \frac{u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x+ u_x^2u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x^3- (2u_xu_yu_{xxy}(1+u_x^2)-4u_{xx}u_{xy}u_x^2u_y)+ u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_x +u_y^2u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_xu_y^2}{(1+u_x^2)^2} 
\end{align*}
So I don't think that you can find this numerator to be zero:
\begin{align*}
 u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x+ u_x^2u_{xyy}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xy}^2u_x^3- 2u_xu_yu_{xxy}(1+u_x^2)+ 4u_{xx}u_{xy}u_x^2u_y+ u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_x +u_y^2u_{xxx}(1+u_x^2)-2u_{xx}^2u_xu_y^2
\end{align*}
Which means there is a mistake in the question or in the comprehension we gave to it.
(assuming I did no mistake)